# Why is /dev/vda1 getting 100%? Disk size is 960GB

Tags: mysql, disk-usage, wordpress

My Wordpress site crashed and when I logged in to the server to check, i am unable to start mysql because for some strange reason 960GB is 100% full (which shouldn't be, I don't have that much articles/images)

Here's the output of df

```
df

Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            24721432         0  24721432   0% /dev
tmpfs            4946144      8776   4937368   1% /run
/dev/vda1      975421904 975405520         0 100% /
tmpfs           24730704         0  24730704   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           24730704         0  24730704   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15        106858      3426    103433   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            4946144         0   4946144   0% /run/user/0
```

Here's the output of

```
sudo find / -type f -printf '%12s %p\n' 2>/dev/null|awk '{if($1>999999999)print $0;}'
  1031798784 /var/lib/mysql/wordpress/wp_posts.ibd
  1015021568 /var/lib/mysql/wordpress/wp_postmeta.ibd
  1073741824 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
  1073741824 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
  7284850736 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

syslog

```
mysqld: Disk full (/tmp/#sql_721_1.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device")
```

Please help. :(

Comment: You need a bigger disk. Oh and you also need to sort that output as those are large files but not in order of size ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't have 960GB worth of data. Some error or misconfigured log file is the culprit. Please help me. I'm new to this.

Comment: Look at the output of `sudo du -sh /*` for the directories that occupies most space, and then drill down to theese, like `sudo du -sh /var`  if var is big.

Comment: @Rinzwind shouldn't we first take a look at where the disk space has gone missing, then we can advise about cleaning up or upgrade hw.

Comment: Why read only 1/2 my comment?  SORT the output.

Comment: The du command takes ages to run because the folder sizes are large with many files. My site is 6 years old and has a big upload folder. Sorting takes more time, as per other experts on stackoverflow forums.

Comment: If I run du on the root, it gets stuck. I waited for 30 minutes with no output. :(

Comment: I've started this command `sudo du -sh /*` but now it's stuck. Will update if I get any output.

Comment: My Wordpress Upload folder (with all media) is 100GB. I'm manually looking at the usual suspects. I still need to find 860 GB of used space. Looking at log folder.